# Disable canonical redirect for multilingual sites in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

My wordpress site is using weglot for multilingual sites. The canonical redirection is on and therefore 
`https://www.example.com/se` 
redirects to
 `https://www.example.com/positions/senior-financial-consultant`.
 How can I prevent this? I want to keep the canonical redirects as well. If I put a '/' at the end, then its fine, but sometimes people don't put the slash.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's indeed caused by the missing slash! However, by default, the trailing slash should be here. Can you reach out to us at support@weglot.com so we can investigate it and help you as soon as possible? Thanks and have a lovely day!

Comment: Hi, thanks! I already did that. Turns out that there is no concrete solution for this now. I had to do some strict 302 redirections for this in server.